# EclipseLink sql load script is not working

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, intellij-idea, eclipselink

I'm using EclipseLink in IntelIj IDEA and I'm trying to setup my Testing persistence unit so it rebuilds the database every time the tests are run and also it populates the database with some seed data.

This is the persistence unit in my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="testingUnit">
        <class>org.cba.entity.Person</class>
        <class>org.cba.entity.InfoEntity</class>
        <class>org.cba.entity.Company</class>
        <class>org.cba.entity.Hobby</class>
        <class>org.cba.entity.Phone</class>
        <class>org.cba.entity.Address</class>
        <class>org.cba.entity.CityInfo</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cba_ca1_test"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="populate.sql"/>
        </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The populate.sql is located in the resources folder as well as META-INF folder with the persistence.xml.

When I use this settings the database is dropped and created every time, but the populate.sql is just not being loaded.

When I write the properties like this:

```
<properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cba_ca1_test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="populate.sql"/>
</properties>
```

Everything works (drop and create and loading of populate.sql), but the execution takes ages. The first settings runs in a few seconds and the second runs for minutes.

And the problem is definitely not the populate.sql file as it only contains about 3 SQL inserts.

I think it's because I use IntelliJ IDEA which generated the eclipselink.* properties. And IntelIj somehow optimizes the settings that uses eclipselink.* naming.

Anybody knows how to make this work, so it doesn't take several minutes?

These are my JPA and MySQL dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have activated the Framework support for EclipseLink in my IntellIJ.

Update:

I added logging property

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
```

And I discovered, that after DROP (which happenes quickly) a new connection is established for each creating table.

Then the Inserting is again pretty quick.

Comment: The LOG would tell you what is taking the time ...

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point I added Fine level logging. The Dropping is fast, but then it appears that new Connection is created every time a table is created.

Comment: sounds like a bug in EclipseLink (IMHO), that you'd need to raise on them if one doesnt exist. I don't use that provider so know of no workarounds

Comment: Show the log and how you are executing the operation, as it doesn't make sense that using one persistence property over another for the same purpose would change connection behavior, leading me to suspect it is likely the tool you are using is performing the operation instead of your JPA provider. Glassfish for instance was known to parse the JPA properties and use its own table creation tool instead.